# Frequency vs time plot python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I have the following code:

```py
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile

fs, data = wavfile.read("New Recording 2.wav")
f, t , zxx = signal.stft(data, fs)
fa = np.array(f)
ta = np.array(t)
plt.plot(ta, fa, np.abs(zxx))
plt.show()
```

I want to plot a graph like this: [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXLpU.png), with time (secs) on x axis and Khz on Y axis.

When I run the above code I run into the value error

> "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (3,) and (2,)"

I thought this was a quirk in numpy hence me converting `f` and `t` to np.arrays instead of the arrays outputted by scipy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you have more x values than y values

Comment: I overcome that by change the npeg on the stft function. However when fixing that I now run into the error: too many values to unpack

Comment: You should add the full error to your question as an edit